# Cycling through Images stored in an array with a button

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to cycle through 5 images with the press of a button once. I'm pretty new to coding and I was asked to fix this code by a friends but I can't see how this isn't working. When I run it on chrome the first image comes up but when I press the button it doesn't change to the next image. I'm using sublime text 2 if thats any use. Here's the code I'm trying to fix

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var trafficlights = new Array(."Traffic Lights Red (4).jpg","Traffic Lights    RY.jpg","Traffic Lights Green.jpg","Traffic Lights Yellow.jpg", "Traffic Lights Red (4).jpg")
var lightcentre = 0;
function lightCycle()

{
 if(++lightcentre == 5)
  lightcentre = 0;

 document.images.banner.src = trafficlights[lightcentre];

}

</script>


</head>


<body>

<img src="Traffic Lights Red (4).jpg" name="banner" > 
<form>
 <input type="button" value="Change lights" name="Change lights"    onclick="lightCycle()">
</form>


</body>



</html>
```

Comment: Why is there a period as the first character of your array values? And the spacing looks a little screwy on the second entry.  Have you inspected your elements using your browser tools?  Seen any console errors?

Comment: The spacing on the second entry isn't actually like that in the code I'm using, it must have been added in transaction. As I said I'm pretty much new to coding, what do you mean by 'period'? I'm afraid I'm not on a suitable computer to check my coding right now.

Comment: I mean, there is literally a period character `.` prior to the filename string, `new Array(."Traffic Lights Red (4).jpg","etc")`, just like @Connor pointed out in his answer. That doesn't belong there.

Comment: oh wow. How did I not see that?! Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

You've got a syntax error in your code here that's causing things to break:

`var trafficlights = new Array(."Traffic Lights Red (4).jpg", ...`

That period doesn't belong there. Removing it appears to make your code function just fine in Firefox on my end.

`var trafficlights = new Array("Traffic Lights Red (4).jpg", ...`

Comment: Thank you for the help. Can't believe I missed that

Comment: Glad I could help! Keep on keepin' on- this JavaScript stuff gets easier to understand with practice.